# How to remove Total and Taxes?

Tags: c#

when I want to remove my Total it removes the total but not the Taxes (BTW).

```
private void btnVerkooplijnVerwijderen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Int32 i;


        // Rijnummer bepalen
        i = dgvVerkooplijnen.CurrentRow.Index;

        // Totaal aanpassen
        dblHKTotaal -= 0;
        dblVerzendkostenTotaal -= 0;
        dblBTWTotaal -= 0;
        dblTotaal -= Convert.ToDouble(dgvVerkooplijnen.Rows[i].Cells["Subtotaal"].Value);
        lblBTWTotaal.Text = "€ " + dblBTWTotaal.ToString("N2");
        lblTotaal.Text = "€ " + dblTotaal.ToString("N2");

        // Rij verwijderen
        dgvVerkooplijnen.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

[image: Application overview image]

Comment: I don't get it, from the image you have added, everything seems to be correct, you have 1 line with a cost of 10 € and 2.1 € (21% belgian taxes) taxes, so, what is your question?

Comment: Also note that you are subtracting 0 from your totals, so, you can hardly call that a change ;)

Comment: when i remove the line the belgian taxes are still showed and the total is then 2.1 euro that needs to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you have created your datatable, I will give you a more direct approach in how you can calculate line totals and table totals. For example to create a full line item, I can set up a datatable in the following way

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add( "Id", typeof(Int32) );
table.Columns.Add( "Code", typeof(String) );
table.Columns.Add( "Description", typeof(string) );
table.Columns.Add( "Quantity", typeof(Int32) );
table.Columns.Add( "ItemPrice", typeof(decimal) );
table.Columns.Add( "SubTotal", typeof( decimal ), "Quantity*ItemPrice");
table.Columns.Add( "Taxes", typeof( decimal ), "SubTotal*0.21");
table.Columns.Add( "LineTotal", typeof( decimal ), "SubTotal + Taxes");
```

On thing you see here is that the calculation logic now becomes a functionality of my datatable. I don't have to calculate all the items separately, upon adding rows, the `SubTotal`, `Taxes` and `LineTotal` are calculated automatically. This is done by using the [`DataColumn.Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx)

I can then add items to it, like for example:

```
table.Rows.Add( 1, "DECA10", "Coffee decafinated", 1, 2.5 );
table.Rows.Add( 2, "ESPR", "Espresso", 2, 2.5 );
```

And then I can use the [`DataTable.Compute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute(v=vs.110).aspx) functionality to calculate my required totals, like so:

```
decimal subTotal = (decimal)table.Compute( "Sum(SubTotal)", "");
decimal total = (decimal)table.Compute( "Sum(LineTotal)", "");
decimal taxTotal = (decimal)table.Compute( "Sum(Taxes)", "");
Int64 quantityTotal = (Int64)table.Compute( "Sum(Quantity)", "");
```

And then show them (either in your program, or in my case inside the Console), like so:

```
Console.WriteLine( "Sub total  = {0} €", subTotal );
Console.WriteLine( "Taxes      = {0} €", taxTotal );
Console.WriteLine( "Total      = {0} €", total );
Console.WriteLine( "Quantity   = {0} pieces", quantityTotal );
```

The example of this small demo program, you can find as a [dotnetfiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KhJHHq)